# Strategies for unloading massive amounts of data from one Redshift table to another?

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, bigdata

My company has a huge amount of data that is gathered about our server usage every month (somewhere in the neighborhood of 10 billion rows).  I have been tasked with unloading the data from this initial table to `S3`, where I then copy it up to a table in a different cluster.  This data is then used for dashboard reporting in `Tableau`.

I'm running into problems where the unload (and to some extent the copy) step are failing intermittently with errors such as `Unexpected error: The server is already closed.`  This makes me think that it is essentially timing out.  There is also strange behavior where it is churning and hanging on the unload step, and after it fails I can see that it unloaded all the data and a manifest file into the bucket.

With all this uncertainty, I am forced to look for other strategies that might distribute the task a little.  I'm very interested in `Spark`, and am currently learning about it using `pyspark`, and am wondering if I could somehow ease the problem with distributed processing.  Would it be possible to just store the data in `ec2` and have Tableau pull from there?  Is there someway to distribute the unload process?

I will include the code from my process below so that if there is some bottleneck I'm causing that I can rectify it:

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging

import boto3
import psycopg2 as ppg2

from inst_utils import aws, misc_utils
from inst_config import config3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = misc_utils.initialize_logger(config3.REQUESTS_USAGE_LOGFILE)

    # Unload step
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    month = timestamp.month
    year = timestamp.year

    s3_sesh = boto3.session.Session(**config3.S3_INFO)
    s3 = s3_sesh.resource('s3')
    fname = 'load_{}_{:02d}'.format(year, month)
    bucket_url = ('canvas_logs/agg_canvas_logs_user_agent_types/'
                  '{}/'.format(fname))
    unload_url = ('s3://{}/{}'.format(config3.S3_BUCKET, bucket_url))
    s3.Bucket(config3.S3_BUCKET).put_object(Key=bucket_url)
    table_name = 'requests_{}_{:02d}'.format(year, month - 1)
    logger.info('Starting unload.')
    try:
        with ppg2.connect(**config3.REQUESTS_POSTGRES_INFO) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            # TODO add sql the sql folder to clean up this program.
            unload = r'''
            unload ('select
                        user_id
                        ,course_id
                        ,request_month
                        ,user_agent_type
                        ,count(session_id)
                        ,\'DEV\' etl_requests_usage
                        ,CONVERT_TIMEZONE(\'MST\', getdate()) etl_datetime_local
                        ,\'agg_canvas_logs_user_agent_types\' etl_transformation_name
                        ,\'N/A\' etl_pdi_version
                        ,\'N/A\' etl_pdi_build_version
                        ,null etl_pdi_hostname
                        ,null etl_pdi_ipaddress
                        ,null etl_checksum_md5
                     from
                          (select distinct
                              user_id
                              ,context_id as course_id
                              ,date_trunc(\'month\', request_timestamp) request_month
                              ,session_id
                              ,case
                              when user_agent like \'%CanvasAPI%\' then \'api\'
                              when user_agent like \'%candroid%\' then \'mobile_app_android\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iCanvas%\' then \'mobile_app_ios\'
                              when user_agent like \'%CanvasKit%\' then \'mobile_app_ios\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Windows NT%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%MacBook%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iPhone%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iPod Touch%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iPad%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iOS%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%CrOS%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Android%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Linux%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Mac OS%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Macintosh%\' then \'desktop\'
                              else \'other_unknown\'
                              end as user_agent_type
                            from {}
                            where context_type = \'Course\')
                            group by
                              user_id
                              ,course_id
                              ,request_month
                              ,user_agent_type')
            to '{}'
            credentials 'aws_access_key_id={};aws_secret_access_key={}'
            manifest
            gzip
            delimiter '|'
            '''.format(
                table_name, unload_url, config3.S3_ACCESS, config3.S3_SECRET)
            cur.execute(unload)
            conn.commit()

    except ppg2.Error as e:
        logger.critical('Error occurred during transaction: {}'.format(e))
        raise Exception('{}'.format(e))

    logger.info('Starting copy process.')
    schema_name = 'ods_canvas_logs'
    table_name = 'agg_canvas_logs_user_agent_types'

    manifest_url = unload_url + 'manifest'
    logger.info('Manifest url: {}'.format(manifest_url))
    load = aws.RedshiftLoad(schema_name,
                            table_name,
                            manifest_url,
                            config3.S3_INFO,
                            config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD,
                            config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO,
                            safe_load=True,
                            truncate=True
                            )
    load.execute()
```

Comment: Strong advice not to use python for *massive amounts*. How about copy or pg_dump ?

Comment: Just trying to understand the why here:)  In my program isn't most of the load on Redshift, and not being bottlenecked by Python?  Or should I really be using something like Scala?  Edit: And looks like pg_dump doesn't currently work with Redshift, and copy can't be used from table to table across clusters.  That's why I'm having to place it in S3 first, then copy it over to the new table.

Comment: I don't know what amazon's `unload` command does, but it must be some kind of warpper around copy (`TO stdout` ?) the `to '{}'` suggests that the stuff is sucked into core memory first. #notsure.

Comment: The `to {}` in this case is where I'm specifying the `s3` bucket, it's not placing it internal memory as far as I know.

Comment: The DISTINCT and GROUP BY are redundant. They'll also make that query very expensive (*especially if the planner doesn't realize they're redundant).

You'd probably be better off dumping one month at a time, especially since you'd probably only need to dump the previous month (and maybe the current).

Comment: @Jim Nasby We are pulling only one month at a time

Comment: I will try removing the distinct and group by clauses.  Why are they redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I think you should probably post another question with details of the `UNLOAD` you've tried.

I've found `UNLOAD` to work *much better* when unloading an entire table, e.g., not using a query.

Try creating a temp table with the subset of data you want to unload, then `UNLOAD` the whole table and then delete the temp table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE a AS SELECT b FROM c WHERE d = e;
UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM a) TO 's3://bucket' CREDENTIALS … ;
DROP TABLE a;
```

Regarding your *actual question* above, I do not think you will have much success with this approach. The bottleneck will not be Spark or Python but simply that Redshift is fundamentally not *designed* for returning large number of rows.

Comment: I will try your approach today, that makes sense.  Are my `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` clauses really redundant in this case as said by another poster

Comment: This worked, at least on my dev server.  I'm about to move it over to prod to try it out there.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Jim Nasby - GROUP BY with DISTINCT are redundant, and also are most likely causes for trouble as they force Redshift to execute the collation of the whole data set on the single Leader node, before copying.

The massive benefit of Redshift's COPY command is that each node, if query allows, can unload its own data in parallel with other nodes. So if you have 10 nodes, all 10 of them can create S3 connection (multiple ones) and start pumping out the data.

In your case, by having this DISTINCT, you essentially disable that as all data needs to be recalculated first.

So I'd join with others saying that it is better to either dump the whole table as is (will be faster and less taxing on the cluster), or do simple incremental upload based on date range, potentially with some other simple conditions (like you have `context_type = \'Course\')`. As long as there are no GROUP BY/DISTINCT/ORDER BYs that should  run in parallel, and be very fast.

Using Spark would make no difference is it would just pump the data via SQL connection first.